# How to replace MS Word apostrophe[ you’re ] to normal text apostrophe[you're] in Java

Tags: java, jsp

When we are displaying text on JSP with MS Word apostrophe[ you’re ] it is getting replaced by ? [you?re] . Please help me to find solution to replace MS Word apostrophe[ you’re ]  to  normal text apostrophe[you're] .

Comment: This post might be useful: http://www.coderanch.com/t/380931/java/java/Parse-Smart-Quotes-regular-quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the character encoding throughout your entire web application to one and same character encoding which supports all the characters you'd like to support. These days it's strongly recommended to choose the UTF-8 character encoding for that.

Seeing the `?` instead of the MS Word "smart quote" `’` indicates that either the HTTP response encoding or that DB table encoding doesn't support the character in question. The first step would be to tell JSP to use UTF-8 to encode the characters which are written to the HTTP response.

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, then the second step would be to check if the DB table and/or the JDBC driver is configured to use UTF-8 to store and/or transfer the data. How to do that depends on the DB make/version used which you didn't tell anything about in your question. So all we can suggest is to just consult its documentation for details.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [od](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_od.htm) or similar you can dump the offending file out and determine the code of the character you're trying to replace. You can then use Java regexps with one of the following [Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) representing character codes:

```
\0n     The character with octal value 0n (0 <= n <= 7)
\0nn    The character with octal value 0nn (0 <= n <= 7)
\0mnn   The character with octal value 0mnn (0 <= m <= 3, 0 <= n <= 7)
\xhh    The character with hexadecimal value 0xhh
\uhhhh  The character with hexadecimal value 0xhhhh
```

e.g.

```
String replaced = oldString.replaceAll("\u1234", ","); // where 1234 is your character code
```